# SIP registration using PjSip library over TCP in Android is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc, sip, screensharing

I want to register my extension (1110) with credentials (username, password and domain) in the sip server using PjSip library over TCP transport type in android kotlin.

I got a reference to do the SIP registration from the below project,
https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android/tree/master
But I think this library is incomplete because once the registration request packet is sent to the server it is not returning any response (200 OK) also Transport type TCP is not working.

My requirement is do screensharing in our application. LinPhone sdk is used now but there is a limitation (screensharing feature is unavailable).

So, by using the webRTC first I need to register sip to my server then connect audio, video calls + screensharing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-GPHNSug2Q - This is the reference code for connecting audio, video calls + screensharing.

Once SIP registration is done using PjSip library then only I can do further coding.